# Как создать представление со всеми значениями из первой таблицы?

Tags: sql

У меня есть 2 таблицы, в первой таблице есть поле с `id` из второй таблицы, которое поддерживает значения `null`.

Я создаю **представление** на основе этих **двух таблиц**, и связываю их через `id`. Всё хорошо, кроме того что строки в которых поле `id=null`, не присутствуют в представлении совсем.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как получить представление со всеми строками из первой таблицы?

Comment: Наверное нужно использовать LEFT JOIN

Comment: да LEFT JOIN помог, спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно использовать LEFT JOIN. Более подробно например тут: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/relational-databases/performance/joins?view=sql-server-2017